# stackoverflow when implement REPEAT UNTIL in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I want to implement a Repeat Until in Scala.

The commented code will throw a StackOverflowException.

But the code now run in main method works.

But I don't know why and what's the difference between these two snippets.

```
object REPEAT{
    class REPEAT(command: => Unit){
        def UNTIL(cond: => Boolean):Unit = {
            command
            if(!cond) UNTIL(cond)
        }
    }

    def REPEAT(command: => Unit): REPEAT = {
        new REPEAT(command)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        /* this code work well */
        var i = 0
        REPEAT { i+= 1; println(i)} UNTIL (i == 100)

        /*
        // something wrong in this code.
        var i = 0
        new REPEAT {
            i += 1; println(i)
        } UNTIL (i == 100)
        */          
    }
}
```

ps: I found the wrong code just change the var i to 1 but don't change it anymore.

The wrong code's output:

> 1
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError   at
>   REPEAT$$anon$1$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.apply$mcV$sp(REPEAT.scala:15)
>     at REPEAT$REPEAT.UNTIL(REPEAT.scala:4)

Comment: it doesn't compile if uncomment your commented code (`var i` defined twice). WIthout it - prints 1 to 100 as expected. If you write `REPEAT { i+= 1; println(i)} UNTIL (i == 100)` twice - it will cause the stackoverflow as it will start from i=101 and end at i=infinity.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't express it clearly. The code which run in the main method is to replace the code commented.

Comment: As it stands, I am pretty sure your `UNTIL` method is not tail-recursive, because it is neither `private` nor `final`. With longer loops you'll get a `StackOverflow` as well. You should add the `@tailrec` annotation to that method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the problem:

```
   new REPEAT {
            i += 1; println(i)
   } UNTIL (i == 100)
```

is equivalent to:

```
   new REPEAT() {
            i += 1; println(i)
   } UNTIL (i == 100)
```

So you're actually creating new instance of `REPEAT` class with `command = ()`, and `i += 1; println(i)` in constructor - so `i++` repeated only once and `()` repeated infinitely.

The right way to call it:

```
    new REPEAT({
            i += 1; println(i)
    }) UNTIL (i == 100)
```

The reason why is you don't have to specify single parameter with `Unit` type explicitly in scala:

```
scala> class Aaaa(a: Unit)
defined class Aaaa

scala> new Aaaa //parenthesis is not required for 'new'
res10: Aaaa = Aaaa@17de44d4

scala> def aaaa(a: Unit) = 5
aaaa: (a: Unit)Int

scala> aaaa()
res13: Int = 5
```